# Split list into list of lists with a list as a parameter for where to split OCaml

Tags: list, split, ocaml, nested-lists

I am new to OCaml and curious as to how to write a function called `Seperate_by` that takes in two parameters, a list and a list of elements on where to split the original list.

For example,

```
Seperate_by [1;2;3;4;5;6;7] [3;5]
```

Should have an output of `[[1;2];[4];[6;7]]` .

Comment: Just as an aside, function names cannot be capitalized in OCaml :)

Comment: What have you tried, and what seems to be the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
let seperate_by l lsep =
  let add acc res = if acc<>[] then acc::res else res in
  let(res,acc)=
    List.fold_right ( fun x (res,acc) ->
      if List.exists ((=)x) lsep then (add acc res,[]) else (res,x::acc)
    ) l ([],[])  
  in
  add acc res
```

Test :

```
# seperate_by [1;2;3;4;5;6;7] [3;5];;
- : int list list = [[1; 2]; [4]; [6; 7]]
# seperate_by [1;2;3;4;5;6;7] [3;5;7];;
- : int list list = [[1; 2]; [4]; [6]]
# seperate_by [1;2;3;4;5;6;7] [1;5;7];;
- : int list list = [[2; 3; 4]; [6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let rec seperate_by l sign= 

  let rec aux2 = function
    (head,[])->(head,[])
   |(head,x::r) -> if List.exists ((=) x) sign then (head,r) 
    else  aux2 (head@[x],r)
  in

  let res = aux2 ([],l) in
  match res with
  |(head,[])->head::[]
  |(sub_list,rest_list) -> (sub_list)::(split rest_list sign)
         ;;
```

(*the function aux2 returns the first sub_list of a list so i keep building the list with the rest of the list and the finally we have the result *)

Note: I saw that your function's name begins bt a uppercase.All variable begins by uppercase letter means a 'type' in Ocaml, so the name of a function should begin by lowercase may be that's your problem ?

Comment: Awesome! Do you know if there is a way to do it using List.fold_left instead of recursion?

Comment: @V. Michel 's ansew is better then mine.In fact, u can use List.fold_left by using `@` or use List.fold_right by using`::` as Michel did in `else (res,x::acc)` u can using List.fold_left by changing it by `else (res,acc@[x])`  of corse you should change the order of parameters in fold_left.

Answer (score 0):

```
let rec seperate_by l sign=
   let rec aux2 = function
      (head,[])->(head,[])
      |(head,x::y::r) when x=y -> if List.exists ((=) x) sign then (head@[],y::r) else  aux2 (head@[x],y::r)
      |(head,x::r) -> if List.exists ((=) x) sign then (head,r) else  aux2 (head@[x],r)
   in
   let res = aux2 ([],l)
   in
   match res with
      |(head,[])->head::[]
      |(sub_list,rest_list) -> (sub_list)::(seperate_by rest_list sign)
```

Comment: I added a new case.Zhenyu's answer is more clear, but i want to know how do you convert it to fold format